# SQL Query for a particular scenario

Tags: sql

Considering the sample table below:

```
Profile_ID  Child_ID

1           1
1           2
1           3

2           1
2           2

3           1
3           2
3           3
3           5
```

I want to construct an SQL query which gives me the profile IDs which are applicable to  children 1 AND 2 AND 3... this implies that profile_ID 2 will not be in the result as profile 2 is only applied to children 1 and 2.. but I expect that profile 3 is included.

My idea is something similar to this

```
SELECT Profile_ID
FROM table
WHERE Child_ID IN (1 AND 2 AND 3)
```

Now, I am well aware that `IN` serves as an `OR` function...
Is there a similar way to achieve similar functionality to the `IN` clause with an `AND` rather than an `OR`?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: very good question! interesting situation!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
select profile_id from t
where child_id in (1, 2 ,3)
group by profile_id
having count(distinct child_id) = 3
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85045/1) to play with.

NOTE: Make sure `3` matches the amount of items in the `in` clause.

Comment: instead of group by profile_id, is it possible to change the select statement to select distinct profile_id?

Comment: @test No. I'm not grouping to get distinct profile_id but rather to be able to perform a count on the resulting group. A distinct clause won't allow me to do that.

Comment: @MostyMostacho: The "SQL-Fiddle" link alone would be worth some "+1" :-)

Comment: Thanks so much.. that makes so much sense :) +1 from me it is :)